# Definite Article Noun with "de" question

Tags: grammaire

So If I want to say, for example

> In this episode of **the** famous cartoon",

and seeing that "cartoon" is masculine in French, do I say

> Dans cet épisode **du** célèbre dessin animé

OR

> Dans cet épisode **de le** célèbre dessin animé.

I mean seeing that I'm using "de" as "of" and "le" as "the" and not for unspecified singular quantity, does the rule de+le=du still apply?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You must use "du" there. The only case where you may write "de le" is if it’s followed by a infinitive verb. Like in « Impossible de le voir » → "Impossible to see it/him".

Comment: Yes, in the *de le* + infinitive case, *le* is a pronoun (it/him) , not an article (the).

Comment: Or rather *le* + verb in any conjugation!